# Golang import package error

Tags: go

> go:5:2: cannot find package "github.com/googollee/go-socket.io" in any of:
>       /usr/local/go/src/github.com/googollee/go-socket.io (from $GOROOT)
>       /Users/YoungHoonKim/Documents/chat/src/github.com/googollee/go-socket.io (from $GOPATH)

I'm getting this error while trying to compile my `chat.go` file with LiteIDE. I'm following a guide to build a chatserver, so I don't know where this package should be. any help?

Comment: Obviously it should be in `/usr/local/go/src/github.com/googollee/go-socket.io` or `/Users/YoungHoonKim/Documents/chat/src/github.com/googollee/go-socket.io` but seems like it isn't. Try running `go get github.com/googollee/go-socket.io`

Comment: Thanks. googollee obviously needed to be downloaded by hand. solved it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Double-check your actual go work directory with `echo $GOPATH` in your terminal.
This will be your starting point to identify if you have this package at all, for example you should be able to see this package doing `cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/googollee/go-socket.io`.

For more details on correct directory location (workspace in general) please check https://golang.org/doc/code.html